# Разделение общего компонента для игрока и врага из за 1 различного признака

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть компонент Health, он полностью подходит как для врага, так и для игрока, но я хочу добавить анимацию получения урона игроку, а у врага такой анимации не планируется, возникает вопрос как добавить включение анимации получения урона в Health, если у врага даже не будет аниматора?Сделать компонент Health базовым и от него реализовать HealthPlayer и HealthEnemy только из-за 1 различия?

Comment: Все куда проще, `Health` вообще не должен заниматься анимациями или любой другой визуализацией, это не его ответственность.

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести поле под Animator, реализовать логику анимации. После, добавить bool переменную, которая будет давать ответ, для кого предназначен этот компонент. Таким образом разделить доп.логику для игрок и врага

И для перфекционизма настроить скрытие поля Animator, если переменная bool = true.

```
public bool enableDisableList = false;

[ShowIf(ActionOnConditionFail.JustDisable, ConditionOperator.And, 
nameof(enableDisableList))]
public string anotherField = "item 2";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]